# How to create a dynamic grid that makes the current selection larger?

Tags: website-design, images

You see website http://stackexchange.com/sites containing lots of images.
By clicking each image it expands and clicking another images it expands and collapse previous clicked image. I have attached images below..

#### Before clicking image webmasters:

[image]

#### After clicking image webmasters:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do here is inspect the source code.

I notice right away each block has `-webkit-transform` assigned to it. For example:

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(288px, 0px, 0px);`

As can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Then, I found the class `isotope-image` assigned to the div. A quick Google search turns up: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html